# Exporting contents of emails to Excel/Google Sheets

Tags: excel, import, outlook

I have quite a few emails that come in on a regular basis with the same email subject (around 10-20 a day) that all follow a set format, and then are manually being entered onto a Google Sheet for Sales staff to access.

Ideally, if I could cut this out of my morning routine it would make my life a lot simpler.

What would be the best way to search Outlook by subject line, and then export the relevant data to an Excel worksheet, so that all I would have to do is import that .xls file onto the shared sheet?

Comment: Did you hear about rules in outlook? You can't copy directly into excel, but you have a lot of other options. Look in Start/move/rules, most of the following is selfexplanatory.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider developing a VBA macro or add-in if you need to install the solution on multiple PCs. See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.